# Any reason not to use Tyvek to cover exposed insulation?

Tags: insulation, child-safety

I have exposed insulation in my garage and the water heater room that is fiberglass and I don't want my kids touching the stuff and playing with it.  I am planning on covering it with Tyvek.  Is there any reason not to do this?

I am not planning on drywalling this since there is wiring behind that I might need access to and the alternative is to rip out the fiberglass and
replace it with something that is safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dupont [does **not** recommend Tyvek for interior walls](http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/construction-materials/building-envelope-systems/faqs/wb-faq.html#Question16). That said, I've seen DIY sites recommending it over studs to protect insulation as you suggest.

What might be the concerns that Dupont has for interior use? Offhand, I can think of two:

- A vapor barrier can cause condensation in walls. *However,* [Tyvek is not a vapor barrier](http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/construction-materials/building-envelope-systems/faqs/wb-faq.html)
- Fire safety might be a concern.Tyvek is [NFPA 285 compliant](http://www.dupont.com/products-and-services/construction-materials/building-envelope-systems/articles/nfpa-285-compliance.html), but that rating is for *exterior* walls. [Tyvek® FireCurb®](http://www.dupont.co.uk/products-and-services/construction-materials/tyvek-building-envelope/brands/tyvek-breather-membrane/products/tyvek-firecurb-housewrap-fire-retardant-membrane.html) is fire-retardant, but *still* is recommended only for external walls.

Apologies, then... this is really *not* an answer: Tyvek *is* being used inside, yet the manufacturer states *it should not be*.

Comment: Dupont isn't specific about why they don't recommend it, or for what interior use.  It could be that it's designed for a specific function on the exterior, and interior use won't work for that function.  But they may have no opinion regarding other uses on the interior, and their recommendations may simply not address other uses (as opposed to explicitly stating that it is bad to put the stuff on the interior for any purpose).

Comment: Got to give this a + it answers the question and the mfg statements. To me it will protect the insulation and kids. If in the future it is covered it probably should be removed but without additional information I believe I would do the same.

Comment: All materials have a “flame spread rating” and “smoke development rating”. While Tyvek has an acceptable rating for both, when it’s exposed in a hazardous environment (yes, a garage is considered hazardous, because of gas, oil, etc. stored in the space) it is more likely to “contribute” to the flame and smoke issue.

Comment: I looked and could not find Tyvek® FireCurb® in the US.  It appears to only be available in Europe.

Comment: Your answer got me curious and I wrote to Dupont asking for clarification of their recommendation.  If I hear back, I'll share it.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would use OSB (Oriented Strand Board) in the same way you might use drywall, but the OSB can be screwed to the wall in fewer places, so it can be easily removed again for access to the wiring. I've used it in my garage because it was actually CHEAPER than drywall! Looks like crap, but so would the Tyvek...
[image: OSB example]

Just make sure to paint it, otherwise the kiddos might get splinters when they run their hands along it.